# c# - How to Populate a complex property

Tags: c#

I have the following classes :

```
public class a
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    private object details { get; set; }
    public object Details
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type == "One")
                details = new DotOne();
            if (Type == "Two")
                details = new DotTwo();
            return details;
        }
        set { details = value; }
    }
}
public class DotOne
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
public class DotTwo
{
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }
}
```

However, although I can populate DotOne and Two separately and then add it to the main a Like :

```
var newDotOne = New DotOne()
{
    a = "Test One",
    b = "Test Two",
    c = "Test Three"
}
var NewA = new a()
{
    Id = "1234",
    Name = "Adam",
    Type = "One",
    Details = newDotOne
}
```

But I can only populate it if I know the choice, and I can't access it any other way
Therefore It will be greatly appreciated if this could be fixed, either by changing the classes or a way to access "Details"

#### Edited

As per @NetMage 's suggestion and to clearify the need, further, here is what i need to achieve:

```
var NewA = new a()
{
    Id = "1234",
    Name = "Adam",
    Type = "One",
    Details = 
    {
        a = "Test One",
        b = "Test Two",
        c = "Test Three"
    }
}
```

or :

```
a.Details.b = "New Test";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access it any other way"? How do you want to access "it"? What even is "it"? Can you show show an attempt at "accessing it any other way"? The getter and setter for `Details` also looks very wrong. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: This design does not make sense to me as type can be set to one but details set to DotTwo. Type property should be readonly and calculated based on details

Comment: @Sweeper I am trying to set Details based on Type

Comment: @Vasya I have tried every Possibilities for the class but couldn't come up with any other logical order

Comment: Please check my answer if it is helpful. thanks

Comment: @Mehrdad_gh: your details are of generic object type so saying "details = value;" will work. Are you talking about constructor here? Maybe you want to have two different constructors for the main class, one that takes DotOne and the other one that takes DotTwo?

Comment: dear @Vasya i did use details = value (as in the above code ) but it still won't work . all i want to do is if a user chooses Type = One, then details should be DotOne

Comment: Try to show some code that displays what you want to do, not what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

you Can do that by replacing the type of details to dynamic type

```
public class a
{
    private string type;
    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set
        {
            if (value == "One")
                Details = new DotOne();
            if (value == "Two")
                Details = new DotTwo();
            type = value;
        }
    }


    private dynamic details;
    public dynamic Details { get { return details; } set { details = value; } }


}
```

this is as what you asked for

```
void Createobj()
{
    var obj = new a() { Type = "One" };
    obj.Details = new DotOne { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c" };
    obj.Type = "Two";
    obj.Details = new DotTwo { d = "d", e = "e" };

    obj.Details.d = "ddd";

 var NewA = new a()
    {
        Type = "One",
        Details =
    {
        a = "Test One",
        b = "Test Two",
        c = "Test Three"
    }
    };
    
    NewA.Details.b = "New Test";
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work as DotOne (if chosen) will not show up in Details

Comment: I am sorry Dear @Amjad but it still won't work, specially because Details is private, it can not even be accessed to populate it

Comment: I thought it was a typo and i changed it myself :) but still no hope

Comment: Dear Amjad, I know once you select obj.Type = "One", you could access job.Details and populate d and e, but this is if you know what the user has selected, if you don't know, then it will not automatically allow to populate the write property, which is the same with my own code

Comment: Lets say I want to chage the value of "e" how could i address it !!?

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it won't replace d and shows it as null

Comment: Dear Amjad on my side, i still get null, unfortunately

Comment: Dear Amjad it is working now but what you have done is similar to what i have done in my code and i think that mine is more subtle. As mentioned, i am looking for a automatic procedure to replace Details with DotOne or DotTwo as there is no point in doing it manually.

Comment: Please accept my asnwer if this is what you want!

Comment: Sorry Dear Amjad, but your solution isn't the answer to the problem

Comment: dear @Mehrdad_gh if you replace the object type to dynamic u can then access the properties as you showed in ur question

Comment: Dear Amjad, I know, but when it is dynamic, then one could add what ever, and it will be accepted :) my problem is that i have to somehow reference the users choice to proceed accordingly. by the way, what i did put in here is just a sample, while the actual choice is much more than the two mentioned above and each with so many properties :))

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic type to achieve this easily.  Refactor your class as so:

```
public class a<TypeOfDetails>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public TypeOfDetails Details { get; set; }
}
public class DotOne
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
public class DotTwo
{
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can instantiate your `a` class with the appropriate details type like so:

```
var newDotOne = New DotOne()
{
    a = "Test One",
    b = "Test Two",
    c = "Test Three"
}
var NewA = new a<DotOne>()
{
    Id = "1234",
    Name = "Adam",
    Type = "One",
    Details = newDotOne
}
```

Comment: I know this is what i can do, even with the sample i posted initially, but the problem is i wouldn't know the users choice if it is DotOne or DotTwo